How to center input in the center of the screen
I'm not new to programming but I am new to HTML. I've been assigned the task of creating a internal webpage. I'm probably getting the cart before the horse some but I'm attempting to style the page as I go. My question is, how can I get these inputs fields to center in the screen?
<body>
        <h1 style="text-align:center;">Request for Production</h1>
        <form name="message" method="post">
            <section>
                <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
                    <label for="date">Date <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                    <input id="date" type="date" value="" name="name" style="font-size: 20px; padding: 5px; color:rgb(220,220,220); border-radius: 3px; height:23px; width:200px; border-width: 1px;">
                    <label for="date"><span style="font-size: 14px;">Date</span></label>
                </div>



                <br style="clear:both;" />
            </section>
            <br>
            <section>
                <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
                    <label for="email">Enter your email <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="email" style="font-size: 16px; padding: 5px; color:rgb(220,220,220); border-radius: 3px; height:20px; width:200px; border-width: 1px;">
                    <label for="date"><span style="font-size: 14px;">example@example.com</span></label>
                </div>
                
                <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
                    <label for="ccemail">Enter CC'ed email <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                    <input id="email" type="text" value="" name="ccemail" style="font-size: 16px; padding: 5px; color:rgb(220,220,220); border-radius: 3px; height:20px; width:200px; border-width: 1px;">
                    <label for="date"><span style="font-size: 14px;">example@example.com</span></label>
                </div>
            </section>
        </form>
    </body>

I've tried various different inline styling but I cannot seem to get it to behave the way I want it to.

There is much that you have to learn an input according to specifications should only have one label. It might inconsistently work but can cause other issues as well are inaccessible. You should learn to use CSS instead of inline style. Then learn to use Flexbox and Grid instead of some 15 years of outdated hacks. <br> is to create linebreaks not to space elements apart. for that you should use margins or gaps.

You can try to use this styling for the form:
form {
   display: flex
   justify-content: center
}

Or this:
div {
   text-align: center
}

Also the input tag has an align attribute that might work for you
<input align="center" id="name_field" name="input_field">


the first 2 options will center everything not just the button. The first on top will place every container next to each other not just centering the element's content. The last option will center the text/value of the input, not the input itself.

apologies, as my knowledge of css is not so complete, i should not have attempted to answer this question
